# Can write review on Ubuntu software center, for ClamTK

Tags: software-center

For some reason I cant write a review for ClamTK, it tells me

```
"The origin of the application cannot be detected. Entering a review is not possible"
```

However I do have it installed and have the latest version, when on the applications page in software center it even says "Remove", were it usually says install, so the software centre knows that it is installed on my pc, else it would say "Install" and not Remove.

So does anyone know why it wont let me write review?

Comment: Where did you install it from?

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing it with synaptic, choose the "remove completely" option to remove all config files as well, then re-install. This should do the same thing:

```
sudo apt-get --purge clamav
```

When you remove via the software center, all the configuration files get left on your system, and when you re-install, they are still there. It's like you never removed it.

I'm not saying this is the problem, but it *could* be the problem.

[Edit] I don't believe either option removes config files in ~/ so you might try looking in your home directory as well for some .clam directory or file you'd want to delete as part of a purge.